# when proxifier is running, eclipse says "Unable to establish loopback connection"

Tags: android, eclipse, port

I've installed ADT Bundle, when the proxifier is running in my windows if I open ADT Bundle it says : "Failed to initialize Monitor Thread: Unable to establish loopback connection
"   and it doesn't compile any program, what should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm facing the same problem as yours. A working solution for me is :

1. Open cmd
2. Type setx _JAVA_OPTIONS -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
3. Open file eclipse.ini ini your eclipse folder, add this line after -vmargs
   -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
4. Open eclipse and see what happens.

Proof : 
[image]

Source : http://hassanfathy.wordpress.com/2013/05/15/mengakali-eclipse-dan-android-sdk-manager-yang-ter-block-proxifier/ 
P.S. It's in bahasa indonesia language. You can use google translate for that site :D

Answer (score 0):

i was facing the same problem and I found a much simpler solution. Find the program that is causing the error in **proxifier**. In my case it was **javaw.exe**. Then make a new **proxification rule** in **proxifier** with action **direct**. Shift this rule above the proxy rule you're using( to give it a higher preference). Then add javaw.exe in the application list, just like I have added in this picture:
[the image for proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VAdPb.png)